# Issue in rendering react component which is a verdaccio package

Tags: reactjs, verdaccio

We are using verdaccio for publishing our react component as an npm package to the **verdaccio** npm registry.
Now, in another react app we are consuming this package, but we are getting error when we are rendering the imported **jsx** code from the package . If anybody has any idea regarding this issue, kindly revert. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the react component we have published as a an npm module to the verdaccio directory.

**react component:**

```
import React from 'react';

class  myInputForm extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <form>
                 Name: <input type="text" name="name" autoComplete="off" /><br />
                 Area: <input type="text" name="area" autoComplete="off"  /><br />
                 Email: <input type="email" name="email" autoComplete="off"  /><br />
                 <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
    

}

export default myInputForm;
```

**React Component where it is consumed. This react component is part of another react app.**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import {MyInputForm} from 'mynpmpackage/src/index';
    const ContactUs = ( ) => {
        return (
            <div style={{backgroundColor:'green', height: '817px'}}>
            <h1>Contact Form</h1>
            <MyInputForm />
            </div>
        )
    }

export default ContactUs;
```

Error on console after npm start:

[image]

Comment: Please do add code as text when asking questions.

Comment: Its a large code so thought of asking about the issue first.